# Creating a matrix of rank r from r number of rank 1 matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am told that all matrices of Rank $r$ can be formed out of the combinations of $r$ number of Rank 1 matrices. So that's the original matrix can be broken down into $r$ number of rank 1 matrices. But I don't understand and see how this is possible.

Say for a matrix of this form:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 & 6\\ 
3 & 0 & 1 & 4\\ 
2 & 1 & 1 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The $rank(A)= 3$.

So if the claim was right, then I can form back the same matrix $A$ with the combination of 3 of Rank 1 matrices. I tried to "emulate" that idea but I just don't totally get how I could do it.

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: What do you mean "created" - "added", "mulitiplied", some other operation?

Comment: oh.. I meant like say for a matrix of rank 3, it can be formed from a combination of 3 of rank 1 matrices.

Comment: BUt are you combining the matrices by adding them, multiplying them or doing something different?

Comment: If you are adding: Take the matrix you get by taking the first row of A and making all the other entries zero, add it to the matrix you get by taking the second row of A and making the other entries zero, and add to the matrix you get from the third row of A with other entries zero. Each of the three matrices trivially has rank 1, and the sum is the matrix you first thought of.

Comment: But this would not be the combination of rank 1 matrices, would it? Actually, I am not sure if the operation between the matrices would be adding or multiplying. I only know that the original matrix can be broken down into $r$ number of rank $r$ matrices and I thought this could be some kind of definition or something of that sort, which I am not aware of.

Comment: If you have a matrix with only one row non-zero it has rank 1.

Comment: yea, I understand that those are rank 1 matrices. But by adding them up this way is totally like just "splitting" them and then joining back. Can this still considered a combination of matrices?

Comment: Well adding matrices creates a combination. That's why I asked the question about what you mean by combination - I can't tell what combination means because you haven't given enough detail - I don't know whether adding counts.

Comment: The example given is not particularly interesting, since its rank equals the number of rows (it has full row rank), so it can be essentially split up into its rows. A more interesting example would have neither full row rank nor full column rank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A=(A_{1}, \dots A_{n}), A_{i} \in K^{m}$, then the rank of $A$ is 
$r=dim(Span(A_{1}, \dots, A_{n}))$. Let $\{v_{1}, \dots v_r\}$ be a basis for it. So, $\forall i=1\dots n, \exists a_{i1}, \dots , a_{ir} \in K$ such that $A_{i}=a_{i1}v_1+\dots + a_{ir}v_r $ and

$A=(a_{11}v_1+\dots + a_{1r}v_r, \dots , a_{n1}v_1+\dots + a_{nr}v_r)$ .

Now you can take $B_j=(a_{1j}v_j, \dots, a_{nj}v_j)$ $\forall j=1, \dots, r$ and observe that $rk(B_j)=1$ and $A=\sum_{j=1}^{r}B_j$.

Here's the example:

$A=(A_1 , A_2, A_3, A_4)$ with 
$A_1=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 3 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$ , 
$A_2=\begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ , 
$A_3=\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ , 
$A_4=\begin{bmatrix}6 \\ 4 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}$ .

$Span(A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4) = R^3$ , and so we can take the standard basis $\{e_1=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
e_2=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
e_3=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
\}$

Now, $A_1=1e_1+3e_2+2e_3$ ,
$A_2=3e_1+0e_2+e_3$ ,
$A_3=2e_1+1e_2+1e_3$ ,
$A_4=6e_1+4e_2+4e_3$ ,

and so I make:

$B_1=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 2 & 6\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

$B_2=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
3 & 0 & 1 & 4\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

$B_3=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
2 & 1 & 1 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$

and $A=B_1+B_2+B_3$.

N.B. The matrixes $B_i$ are so "well done" in this case because we could take the standard basis as basis of the columns.

Comment: I don't understand why the first row of the text is that. I wrote it between "and" and "."

Comment: Done, now it's ok.

Comment: Give me a few mins. I am trying out your answer and will get back to you in a bit. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why I followed your steps but I still don't get it. Could you do an example based on the matrix I posted in my question? thanks!

Comment: come to think about it, if I didn't use the standard basis but the original vectors instead, which is what I have done earlier on my own, the matrix that I produce would be very different.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write SVD http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition in the form of what you need.